# How to unpack bytes in "pairwise reversed" order BA DC?

Tags: perl, byte, unpack

I have a binary string where the bytes are reversed in the following way: The file contains e.g the four bytes `0x18 0xb1 0x35 0x41` and should be interpreted as `0xb1 0x18 0x41 0x35` into my perl string or array. That is, every pair of bytes is reversed.

How can I use `unpack` to unpack this format?

I also wonder if this kind of packing/format is standard, does it have a name? I apologise if I'm using the wrong terms, I'm not used to byte-level manipulation.

Comment: This is called little endian.

Comment: @tkausl I had only heard little/big endian used in reference to bit order, not byte order?

Comment: Little endian and big endian always applies to bytes, not bits. There's no way to address bits, so the concept makes no sense for bits.

Comment: @ikegami thank you for clarifying and for you great answer! I checked the wikipedia page and found this, so I think it was my telecom and mcu experience hindering my learning :) "Endianness may also be used to describe the order in which the bits are transmitted over a communication channel, e.g., big-endian in a communications channel transmits the most significant bits first. Bit-endianness is seldom used in other contexts."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have `"\x18\xb1\x35\x41..."` and you want `"\xb1\x18\x41\x35..."`

```perl
$s =~ s/(.)(.)/$2$1/sg;
```

```perl
my $out = $in =~ s/(.)(.)/$2$1/srg;
```

```perl
my $out = pack "n*", unpack "v*", $in;
```

```perl
my $out = pack "C*", unpack "(xCXXCx)*", $in;
```

... or an array containing `0xb1, 0x18, 0x41, 0x35, ...`.

```perl
my @out = unpack "C*", $in =~ s/(.)(.)/$2$1/srg;
```

```perl
my @out = unpack "C*", pack "n*", unpack "v*", $in;
```

```perl
my @out = map { $_ >> 8, $_ & 0xFF } unpack "v*", $in;
```

```perl
my @out = unpack "(xCXXCx)*", $in;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
unpack( 'SS', $bytes );
```

Comment: This depends on the computer you are running the code on. For example, if your machine is using an Intel processor, `S` will use [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) interpretation, on the other hand on a Cray it will use big endian, see [perldoc pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack). You can force little endian interpretation by using `S<S<` instead of `SS`